Sending PDF to gemini-1.5-pro-latest fail with 500 error
Below is a snippet that sends a prompt and a pdf file to gemini.
def runGemini(prompt, model, document=None):

    model = genai.GenerativeModel(model)
    content = prompt
    if document:
        content = [
            document,
            "What is this document?",
        ]

    response = model.generate_content(
        content,
        
    )
    return response.text

And here I generate the content part for PDF:
import base64
bytes = pdf_file.getvalue()
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(bytes).decode("utf-8")
blob = glm.Blob(mime_type="application/pdf", data=base64_bytes)
document = glm.Part(inline_data=blob)


Please edit your question and include [example]

First I had a hard time recreating this as i was trying to guess what and how you have created pdf object.
I ended up doing this
create document
To create a document i have done this. I cant see what you are doing.  but it does recreate the issue.
def get_document(pdf_file):
    bytes = pdf_file.getvalue()
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(bytes).decode("utf-8")
    blob = glm.Blob(mime_type="application/pdf", data=base64_bytes)
    return glm.Part(inline_data=blob)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    pdf_data = b"PDF file content here"
    pdf_file = BytesIO(pdf_data)
    document = get_document(pdf_file)
    print(document)
    

When I print the document object returned I get.
inline_data {
  mime_type: "application/pdf"
  data: "PDF file content here"
}

The reason why this would fail is that the mime type for this is not "application/pdf" its "text/basic"
If you are trying to load the byte array for a pdf file directly into a prompt thats not going to work as far as i know its not supported you need to load the text for the pdf and then send it as "text/basic"
from the docs
Content Blob
Currently accepted mime types are

The IANA standard MIME type of the source data. Accepted types include: "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/heic", "image/heif", "image/webp".

I did get it to accept "text/basic" though but "application/pdf" is not accepted at this time.
I did email the team telling them i think that they should be more clear that the issue is with the mime type and not just kick out a 500 error

I tried the bytes directly, but I saw this documentation saying it should be base64
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/gemini#request_body
The base64 encoding of the image, PDF, or video to include inline in the prompt. When including media inline, you must also specify MIMETYPE.

That's Vertex API your not using Vertex API your using GenerativeModel which is the api behind AI studio.   See here... for models supported by Google AI they are "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/heic", "image/heif", "image/webp"

There is a pdf parsing library made by Google developer expert Tanaike. In this fork I cloned tanaike's library with a README file. https://github.com/Aaituov/Processing-Various-Types-of-Invoices-using-Gemini-1.5-API-with-Google-Apps-Script?tab=readme-ov-file .

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
